# Kernel downgrade, UUID not found initramfs

Tags: 18.04, grub2, kernel, uuid

I have a freshly installed 18.04 box. Updates were installed and rebooted. It's running kernel 4.15.0-74 without an issue:

```
root@restore:~# uname -a
Linux restore 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But due to incompatibility with a third party vendor I had to downgrade the kernel to 4.15.0-72. So.. I installed the package and rebooted into that kernel.

However.. I'm thrown back to initramfs immediately, after which it tells me:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Missing moduiles (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=2e897a65-bbcc-426d-a72e-8aca96121c80 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

The UUID is correct:

```
root@restore:~# blkid /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: UUID="2e897a65-bbcc-426d-a72e-8aca96121c80" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="22caffaa-6efd-406b-acba-dbd8a53c72d1"
```

I've added a rootdelay=60 to the grub config, ran update-grub again, no luck.

```
root@restore:~# cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noresume rootdelay=60"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

I also regenerated the initrd and run update-grub again. No luck.

```
root@restore:~# update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-72-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-72-generic
```

More verbose output can be found: https://pastebin.com/8PEwkh05

And contents of fstab as requested below:

```
root@restore:~# cat /etc/fstab
UUID=2e897a65-bbcc-426d-a72e-8aca96121c80 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Am I missing something blindingly obvious here?
Hardware is a QEMU VM. I'm able to reproduce this on each VM I build from the install ISO.

Comment: Please show `update-initramfs  -u -v -k 4.15.0-72-generic` much output and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: re: *"incompatibility with a third party vendor I had to downgrade the kernel to 4.15.0-72"*. What incompatibility?

Comment: @heynnema Their kernel module doesn't support -74 yet. Not really an issue now, since the module is not in place yet.

Comment: Are you using a custom .iso?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: No, default 18.04 install ISO from ubuntu.com site.

Comment: It sure looks custom. None of the file outputs look standard. re: "I had to downgrade the kernel to 4.15.0-72. So.. I installed the package and rebooted into that kernel."... What package(s) did you install, and where did you get them from? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Have you edited /etc/fstab, and checked the other items in my answer?

Comment: @heynnema I made some changes to fstab, per usual procedure on other boxes. 
But even if I install 18.04 from scratch, using the 18.04 server ISO from ubuntu.com - I run into the same issue. Install (default options plus openssh), install linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic from the ubuntu repo, reboot - pick that kernel - and no boot.

Comment: @Johan when you installed -72-generic, did you also install the headers, modules, and module-extras? From the STOCK 18.04 install, without modifying /etc/fstab or anything else, just downgrading to -72, doesn't boot?

Answer (score 0):

re: "*I'm able to reproduce this on each VM I build from the install ISO.*"

Is this a standard Ubuntu .iso, or "something custom" .iso (which I suspect)?

---

**In reviewing your log**, I see...

```
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/panic/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-block/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-bottom/ORDER ignored: not executable
```

You might wish to review these.

**Also, in your /etc/fstab**, I see...

```
UUID=2e897a65-bbcc-426d-a72e-8aca96121c80 / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

and it should be...

```
UUID=2e897a65-bbcc-426d-a72e-8aca96121c80 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

**And in /etc/default/grub**, I see...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noresume rootdelay=60"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true"
```

why the need for these parameters?